# Search the files in drectory with pattern matching using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, boost-filesystem, system.io.file

I am working on migration of legacy Windown form app wrriten in vb.net to .net core api (C#).

There is as an code statement written in VB.net to search the file in directory

```
Function HasDoc(ByVal branch As String, ByVal sender As String, ByVal appName As String) As Boolean
     Dim strPath = "T:\" + appName + branch + "\" + sender + "\_" + branch + "_*.*"
     dim ls_files = Dir(strPath, FileAttribute.Archive)
     dim bolExist as Boolean
     If ls_files = Nothing Then
        bolExist = False
     Else
        bolExist = True
     End If
     return bolExist 
End Function
```

I am using c# statement to replicate below line of code

```
dim ls_files = Dir(strPath, FileAttribute.Archive)
```

**C# Code**

```
    public bool HasDoc(string appName, string branch, string sender)
    {
       
        var filesPath = "T:\\" + appName + branch + @"\" + sender;
        var strPatt = "_" + branch + "_*.*";
       
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(filesPath))
             return Directory.EnumerateFiles(filesPath, strPatt).Any();

        return false;
                    
    }
```

Code I written in C#, performance is very slow and also I am not sure how to use `FileAttribute.Archive`? where legacy code performance comparatively faster than mine, the file location where above code searching the files contain millions of documents.

Please suggest what I can use to replicate the same Vb.net code behaviour

Comment: Whats the content of the variable `filesPath` ?

Comment: You do realise your c# doesn't compile? - https://dotnetfiddle.net/FQ4kXv

Comment: hi @RandRandom, I updated my post, sorry I picked only selected line of code in inital draft, corrected now

Comment: still not compilable, I am picky about this because of your claim `performance is very slow` - can't really say, what your perforamcne issue is when you don't show us what you are actually doing, and since your code doesn't compile I am pretty sure you aren't showing us what you are really doing - which therefor can't be analyzed for performance issue (edit: to late)

Comment: That's not VB.NET code, it's VB 6 from the 1990s. `System.IO.Directory` is a .NET class usable from any language. `Dir` is a legacy keyword mapped to the actual .NET classes. Instead of trying to just convert 30-year old code, try to understand what it actually does first and *then* try to rewrite it

Comment: @RandRandom, I updated the post with function now, earlier I picked only line of code with changed variable names while posting here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , because of 30-year old code we received as legacy, there no enough documentation available and people who are using the feature does not know how code behind fetching the files! for them they just know how to pull the files from application. It’s not something we are replicating the app as is but wherever we does not have enough information just trying to replicate the same feature and this is one of them.

Comment: Programming doesn't work that way. You need to understand what you're doing first. In this case, you can use the functions in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.*` namespace, which includes [Dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.dir?view=net-7.0) as well. Underneath though, the code [just loops over all FileSystemInfo objects matching the pattern](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f1819bd78f0e7506b8c3c7f90b47aa41b0e22c6f/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/CompilerServices/IOUtils.vb#L117) and checks the attributes

Answer (score 1):

The call `Dir(strPath, FileAttribute.Archive)` searches for a file that matches the pattern and has the `Archive` attribute set. `Dir` is actually a VB6 function that remained in VB.NET only to ease migration to the new environment. Underneath it uses the same classes that C# does, eg [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f1819bd78f0e7506b8c3c7f90b47aa41b0e22c6f/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/CompilerServices/IOUtils.vb#L64). It's not possible to filter by attribute, so the implementation loops over all the files and checks their attributes.

The `Microsoft.VisualBasic.*` convenience libraries allow you to use the same functions as VB.NET, eg [Dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.dir?view=net-7.0#microsoft-visualbasic-filesystem-dir(system-string-microsoft-visualbasic-fileattribute)) but these are rarely used nowadays.

You can use the `DirectoryInfo` class in C# directly. `GetFileSystemInfos` returns an array with objects representing all contents of a folder, both directories and files. You can use `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` instead to return an `IEnumerable<>` that only returns items as you read them. Since you only want files, you can use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `EnumerateFileSystemInfos`. This returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` instead of a `string[]`, which allows you to check a file's attributes.

For example:

```
var dir= new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
var pattern=$"_{branch}_*.*";

var files=dir.EnumerateFiles(pattern);
var found=files.Any(file=>file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttribute.Archive));
```

You can swap `EnumerateFiles` with `GetFiles` or even `GetFileSystemInfos` to see if this affects performance.

All these functions accept an [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-7.0) parameter that can be used to specify recursion depth, buffer sizes etc.

```
var options=new EnumerationOptions {
    BufferSize = 16384
};
var files=dir.EnumerateFiles(pattern,options );
```

Comment: I am trieng to usderstand how 'Archive' attribude can applied to file? I mean at which event it will applied ? do you have any Idea?

Comment: That's a file attribute used in multiple file systems [going back to CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) to mark files that have changed since the last backup (whatever that may mean). The "backup" program or script clears this after copying the file. The attribute can be set or cleared manually, which makes it unsafe. Modern backup programs don't depend on it. I suspect the original code used it to find and process modified files periodically.